# Calculating state fidelity and space complexity of Minimum Eigen Optimizers (VQE, QAOA and Grover Optimizer) in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, vqe, optimization, qaoa, fidelity

I'm a beginner in using Qiskit and my Computer Science background is not extensive. But I understand the Quantum Physics aspects of it relatively well.

I solved a QUBO problem in Qiskit using VQE (with CVaR), QAOA and Grover Optimizer, and got the correct results with all three and wish to compare the performance of each. I have already done that for execution time using `time.process_time()` for each and averaging over 15 runs, at relevant intervals.

I would also like to compare the state fidelities and memory used up by each (for space complexity), but don't know what to import and which function to execute from the qiskit library. I also am not sure how to call for the final state-vector results/density matrices that are stored in the result.

Can you please help me with this? Would also appreciate if you can tell me what other metrics exist that can help me compare the performance of each QA.

Answer (score 0):

See the [qiskit.quantum_info](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/quantum_info.html) documentation and in particular the following documentations:

1. [state_fidelity](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.state_fidelity.html#qiskit.quantum_info.state_fidelity) method.
2. [Statevector](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.html#qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector) class.
3. [DensityMatrix](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.DensityMatrix.html#qiskit.quantum_info.DensityMatrix) class.

Comment: I already saw these, but I still don't understand what to do with that. Would be helpful to see an example using code on how to initialize variables, etc.